# How to build and manipulate the color of 4 squares?

Tags: html, css

I am asked to build an HTML and CSS page which contains 4 different colored squares that have a double size of each other(For ex. First one 2x2 px, second one 4x4, third one 8x8 and fourth one 16x16), and when the cursor is hovered on the square, the corresponding square receives the color of the square next to it.

Comment: Could you please share your code so far? The manipulation depends on your requirements. Are you trying to change colors continuously, on click, on user action, etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
<div class="box4"></div>
<style>
 .box1{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:blue
}
 .box2{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:black
 }
.box3{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:yellow
}
.box4{
 width:160px;
 height:160px;
 background-color:green
} 
<script>
 document.querySelector(".box1").addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){
 document.querySelector(".box3").style.backgroundColor="red";
})
<style>
```

This is a link of a demo that does that for the first box. You will have to set the boxes that should change manually 
https://jsfiddle.net/xj60tq4d/1/

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is short snippet for you. It shows the main concept, then you can tune it somehow to achieve exactly what you need.

```js
const INIT_SIZE = [20,20];
const COLORS = ['red','green','blue','yellow'];

const squares = COLORS.map((color, index) => {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.style.width = INIT_SIZE[0] * Math.pow(2, index) + 'px';
  el.style.height = INIT_SIZE[1] * Math.pow(2, index) + 'px';
  el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  return el;
});

squares.forEach((sq) => {
  sq.addEventListener('mouseover', (ev) => {
    const tgt = ev.target;
    const curr = squares.indexOf(tgt);
    const newIndex = (curr + 1) == squares.length ? 0 : (curr + 1);
    tgt.style.backgroundColor = squares[newIndex].style.backgroundColor;
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.